# Do bit field types need to be the same?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I'm trying to get a definitive answer to this question.
Consider the following:

```
struct MyStruct {
    uint16_t a : 4;
    uint8_t b : 4;
}
```

Is this correct?

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 |  9 |  8 |  7 |  6 |  5 |  4 |  3 |  2 |  1 |  0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|                                       |         b         |         a         |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Or is this correct?

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    | 22 | 21 | 20 | 19 | 18 | 17 | 16 | ... |  7 |  6 |  5 |  4 |  3 |  2 |  1 |  0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|                   |         b         | ... |                   |         a         |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I guess my question is three folds.
1. Does changing the type in the declaration sequence move the "cursor" to the next type boundary?
2. Is this an illegal declaration?
3. What do I do if I want the type to be the smallest size to represent its content? Assume I have a block of 64 bits that I want to split into bit fields. Do I need to declare every bit field as `uint64_t myVar : 4` even if `myVar` fits into a `uint8_t`?

Comment: I would say that there is extra padding after `b` (to a total of 32 bits and not 16 or 24 as in your proposals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the bit fields are layed out is implementation defined;
there's no guarantee that you'll get either of these.  But
a change in type does not require that the compiler go to some
new boundary.  (On the other hand, using things like `uint16_t`
as a bit field type is a bit silly.  The only reason to use
`uint16_t` is that for some reason, you need exactly 16
bits—a rarity in itself—and if you're using bit
fields, you'll obviously not get 16 bits.)

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that `a` would take 16bits in memory even if only the first 4 would be used and that `b` would take 8bits in memory if even if the first 4 would be used?

Comment: @bensarz yes you are wrong.  It is implementation defined.  The implementation can do nearly anything: it could add 3MB of padding between them, or 0 bits.

Comment: I accepted this answer because of the last sentence `The only reason to use...not get 16 bits`. This is what helped me understand the intricacies of what I was asking. Was torn between both answers. Thanks to all!! :D

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

The ISO/IEC 14882:1998 C++ standard (9.6 Bit-fields [class.bit]) says:

> Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined.
>   Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined.
>   Bit-fields are packed into some addressable allocation unit.
>   [Note: bit-fields straddle allocation units on some machines and not on others. Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left on some machines, left-to-right on others. ]

So…

1. It's implementation defined.
2. It's not an illegal declaration.
3. There's no portable way to force the type to be as small as possible and you don't need to declare every bit field as `uint64_t` if it fits in a `uint8_t`.